# Python 3 - TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, unicode-string

I'm working on a lesson from Udacity and am having some issue trying to find out if the result from this site returns true or false. I get the TypeError with the code below.

```
   from urllib.request import urlopen
    #check text for curse words  
    def check_profanity():
        f = urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=shit")
        output = f.read()
        f.close()
        print(output)
        if "b'true'" in output:
            print("There is a profane word in the document")

    check_profanity()
```

The output prints `b'true'` and I'm not really sure where that 'b' is coming from.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In python 3 strings are by default `unicode`. The `b` in `b'true'` means that the string is a byte string and not unicode. If you don't want that you can do:

```
 from urllib.request import urlopen
 #check text for curse words  
 def check_profanity():
    with urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=shit") as f:
        output = f.read().decode('utf-8')
        if output:
            if "true" in output:
                print("There is a profane word in the document")

check_profanity()
```

Using `with` will close the `urlopen` connection automatically.